# How to change Tab Bar icon color or text color from Storyboard in new Xcode version 6.0.1?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

How to change Tab Bar icon color or text color from the storyboard in new Xcode version 6.0.1?

Here's a picture to illustrate what I have now:

[image: x]

My icon color is black if you can see:

[image: x]

I want to change the icon and the text color in the way I want from the storyboard, if it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried setting barTintColor of tabbar?

Comment: Do you how to use a search engine?

Comment: This yellow color of the background changed in bar tint . I searched online but could not find anything that helped me so much, that's why I asked the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i have done it through code

To change selected Icon color:

```
[_tabController.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

To change Text Color:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[UIColor yellowColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Medium" size:11.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Medium" size:11.0]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```